# How to test multiple pull-requests at once on github?

Tags: git, github

I reported a bug to an open-source repository on Github. They acknowledged the bug and created multiple pull-requests that supposedly fixed the bug. The problem is I don't know how I can easily test it out. If they only create a single PR, I know I can easily test it out with

```
git fetch upstream pull/<pullrequest_id>/head:pr
git checkout pr
```

Checkout to one of the PR and manually apply the rest is very tedious because the changes for each of the PR are huge. What is an easy way for me to test all the PRs at once? The reason they create multiple pull-requests is that they breakdown the bug I filed into multiple sub-bugs, and each of the PRs fixes each sub-bug.

Comment: You could create a local branch and merge all of the PR branches into that branch.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to fetch all the PR branches. For example, you can do this one at a time with `git fetch upstream pull/<id>/head`. Then create a local branch to merge all of the PR branches into:

```
git checkout -b bug_fix master
git merge pull/<id>/head #repeat for each PR
```

This will allow you to test them all in aggregate, but not individually.

If you need to test each PR individually, and you can do this with the automated test suite, you could write a bash script or batch file to iterate over the list of PRs.

Comment: How to merge upstream PR into local? Tried something like `git merge upstream pull/129/head` but it said `merge: upstream - not something we can merge`.

Comment: @user3667089 `git merge` takes branch names as its arguments. You are passing `upstream` which isn't a branch name. First you need to fetch all the PR branches: `git fetch upstream 'pull/*'`. Then you need to do `git merge upstream/pull/129/head`.

Comment: It said `fatal: Invalid refspec 'pull/*'`. However, I found a stupid way to make it work. Basically `git fetch upstream pull/129/head:pr129`, `git fetch upstream pull/129/head:pr130`, `git fetch upstream pull/129/head:pr131`, and then `git merge pr129`, `git merge pr130`, `git merge pr131`.

Comment: @user3667089 I assume the `pull/129` in every one of your commands is a copy/paste error, correct? Glad you found something that works for you.

Comment: If you could list out the exact git commands in your answer for us to learn that would be amazing. I will also accept your answer if I can replicate your solution.

Comment: Running your command `git merge pull/129/head` results in the error message `merge: pull/129/head - not something we can merge`